# How to highlight current rendered line at mouse pointer, in HTML? (Not table/rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to highlight the current line when mouse moves, is it possible?

It's not table rows, just plain text in paragraphs.

I'm writing a reading helper plugin for `Google Chrome`, to help browsing within a big chunk of text.

Comment: it is easy when every line is in a table row or a div

Comment: use the hover property in CSS. if you need to do with jquery. you can dfine the rule even in jquery or javascript as well as css

Comment: I don't know if there's any semantic block called "line" you can deal with. You can use Javascript to highlight sentences perhaps but not rows.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your definition of "line". If it's a table row or something you can refer to, you can simply do something like this

```
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td> Item 1</td><td> Item 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> Item 1</td><td> Item 2</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And use this in your stylesheet

```
table tr:hover td {
      background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: Nice simple answer that op should be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight Table row then apply this

```
<STYLE>
<!--
  tr { background-color: #DDDDDD}
  .initial { background-color: #DDDDDD; color:#000000 }
  .normal { background-color: #CCCCCC }
  .highlight { background-color: #8888FF }
//-->
</style>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFCC00" WIDTH="100"><b>Brand</b></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFCC00" WIDTH="100"><b>Dimensions</b></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFCC00" WIDTH="100"><b>Price</b></td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#CCCCCC;" 
  onMouseOver="this.className='highlight'" onMouseOut="this.className='normal'">
  <td>Row A</td>
  <td>200x300</td>
  <td>$200,000.00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ugh! Why not just use the `:hover` pseudo class rather than the onMouseOver thingy?

Answer (score 0):

If each line is enclosed with in HTML element of there own the and event handler can be attached.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.4.2.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".lineclass").hover(function() {
                    $(this).css("backgroundColor","red");
                    },
                    function() {
                    $(this).css("backgroundColor","");
                });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <p class="lineclass">This is line 1</p><br />
        <p class="lineclass">This is line 2</p><br />
        <p class="lineclass">This is line 3</p><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it was done with css rather than javascript. I would have given this answer a yes. :-)